# how to plot Mapping in a R2BayesX model

Tags: bayesian

Dear all I am a student and I am doing my thesis  on disease mapping, and  I try to solve it by mapping of the spatial covariate. I try to solve this problem for a long period, maybe more than 2 months, but I could not  got the solution yet.  for my study a have a plenty of covariates(categorical,metrical and spatial covariates) like

y be response variable

x 1 be the first categorical variable

x2 be the second categorical variable etc for the categorical variable and let the metrical covariates

x3 be the non-linear effect on response variable y

x4 be the non-linear effect on response variable y

x5 be the spatial  effect on response variable y and the like

I try to plot the spatial component for any time. But I did not touch the solution and my thesis stopped here.

So anyone who can help on it  how to  Map my response variable in the R program, please help me how to write the code for this. for further detail, I have attached sample mapping plot of Malawi that I want to do

ig 4. The 95% posterior credible intervals map for the spatial effects from the Gaussian model. Red means positive effect, green means negative effect and grey means insignificant effect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoS59.png)